# Why do I get a deprecationWarning: Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge is deprecated. Please upgrade to Selenium 4?

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following selenium code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from msedge.selenium_tools import EdgeOptions
from msedge.selenium_tools import Edge
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

options= EdgeOptions()
options.use_chromium=True
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

driver=Edge(executable_path=r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Automated\msedgedriver.exe', options=options)

params={'behavior':'allow','downloadPath':os.getcwd()}
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior',params)

driver.get("https://www.ons.gov.uk/peoplepopulationandcommunity/healthandsocialcare/healthandwellbeing/datasets/worriesaboutreturntoschoolorcollege")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[3]/div/div[1]/section[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/a"))).click()
```

When I run the code, I get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: Selenium Tools for Microsoft Edge is deprecated. Please upgrade to Selenium 4 which has built-in support for Microsoft Edge (Chromium): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/#upgrading-from-selenium-3
```

How can I adjust the code so that the warning does not appear?

Comment: Open the terminal and run `pip install selenium --upgrade`. Then run your code and see what happens

Comment: It says Found existing installation: selenium 4.1.3. I get the same warning. I think it's more to do with the outdated syntax I'm using.

Comment: Which is the line giving the error? Replace `Edge(executable_path='...')` with `Edge(service=Service('...'))` and to use this you have to put this at start of the file `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service`

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. Please suggest it as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

edge_path = r'C:\Users\A\Desktop\Automated\msedgedriver.exe'
service = Service(executable_path=edge_path)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service = service)

Comment: Full code I used is above, might be clearer for others if you post that. So yes, I should upgrade selenium to the 4.1.3 and write the above code.

Comment: Do you still want that I write an answer with the `Service` thing so that you can accept it, or you will accept the answer by the other user?

Comment: Please put down your answer with the service thing.

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you that you need to upgrade to the latest selenium because your current browser doesn't support selenium 4. So either you upgrade your selenium or downgrade to a older version of your browser.

Comment: It says Found existing installation: selenium 4.1.3. I get the same warning. I think it's more to do with the outdated syntax I'm using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You are correct in that I need to upgrade selenium but the code had to be changed also.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
Edge(executable_path='...')
```

with

```
Edge(service=Service('...'))
```

and put this at the beginning of the script

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
```